# Stata: How to top-code a variable

Tags: stata

Using the auto.dta data, I want to top-code the PRICE variable at the median of top X%. For example, X% could be 3%, 4%, etc. How can I do this in Stata?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In answering your question, I am assuming that you want to replace all the values above, say top `10%`, with value say `X`(`top 90%` in the following code).

Here is the sample code:

```
program topcode
    sysuse auto, clear
    pctile pct =  price, nq(10)
    dis r(r9) 
    gen newprice=price
    replace newprice=r(r9) if newprice>r(r9)
end
```

Comment: Have a look at the `xtile` command for what seems to me like a more straightforward implementation of what you are looking for (recoding to quantiles).

Comment: If you want the result, not a new variable, consider using _pctile rather than pctile. (In this example the new variable pct is redundant.)